# purrr::map_int: Can't coerce element 1 from a double to a integer

Tags: r, purrr

I am having the weirdest bug with `map_int` from the `purrr` package.

```r
# Works as expected
purrr::map_int(1:10, function(x) x)
#>  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

# Why on earth is that not working?
purrr::map_int(1:10, function(x) 2*x)
#> Error: Can't coerce element 1 from a double to a integer

# or that?
purrr::map_int(1:10, round)
#> Error: Can't coerce element 1 from a double to a integer
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

I run 3.5.2 in rocker container (Debian) with the latest github version of everything:

```r
sessioninfo::package_info("purrr")
#>  package  * version    date       lib source                             
#>  magrittr   1.5.0.9000 2019-03-28 [1] Github (tidyverse/magrittr@4104d6b)
#>  purrr      0.3.2.9000 2019-03-28 [1] Github (tidyverse/purrr@25d84f7)   
#>  rlang      0.3.2.9000 2019-03-28 [1] Github (r-lib/rlang@9376215)       
#> 
#> [1] /usr/local/lib/R/site-library
#> [2] /usr/local/lib/R/library
```

Comment: Can you try with `map_dbl`

Comment: The doc says `map_lgl(), map_int(), map_dbl() and map_chr() each return an atomic vector of the indicated type (or die trying).`. It seems they don't try very hard :), but I believe this is expected, you could use `purrr::map_chr(1:10, function(x) 2*x)` because you'd be coercing to a more general type (i.e. conversion always works), here you would like a double to be coerced to integer (`2` is a double so the result is as well), and `purrr::map_int` doesn't even want to try that (it would require checking all values).

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper As far as I am concerned, this is a bug. As you say, it is really inconsistent with all the other map function that perform an implicit conversion! Consider that `purrr::map_df(1:10, function(x) list(a = 2*x))` works. So does `purrr::map_chr(1:10, function(x) x)`. In my real use case, I use `floor`, and having to use `as.integer` defeats the whole point. You can argue that this particular cast leads to information loss but then why allow implicit casting from double to character, which causes loss of precision when casting back to numeric?

Comment: @IceCreamToucan Yes, on reflection it does make sense. Quite limiting though, considering the number of functions that return numeric values even for integers (e.g. `round`, `floor`, etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation from `help(map)` says

> The output of .f will be automatically typed upwards , e.g. logical ->
>   integer -> double -> character

It appears to be following the larger ordering given in `help(c)`. For example, this produces an error `map_dbl(1:10, ~complex(real = .x, imaginary = 1))`.

> NULL < raw < logical < integer < double < complex < character < list <
>   expression

As you can see in that ordering, double-to-integer is a downward conversion. So, the function is designed to not do this kind of conversion.

The solution is to either write a function `.f` which outputs integer (or lower) classed objects (as in @Stéphane Laurent's answer), or just use `as.integer(map(.x, .f))`.

This is a kind of [type-checking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Type_checking), which can be a useful feature for preventing programming mistakes.

Answer (score 5):

`2*x` is not an integer because `2` is not. Do instead

```
purrr::map_int(1:10, function(x) 2L*x)
```

Comment: Sure. This is just really inconsistent with all the other map function that perform an implicit conversion! "Can't coerce from a double to a integer" is really "Don't want to ...". Consider that `purrr::map_df(1:10, function(x) list(a = 2*x))` works. So does `purrr::map_chr(1:10, function(x) x)`. In my real use case, I use `floor`, and having to use `as.integer` defeats the whole point.