# R formatting only for integers, removing decimals

Tags: r

How can decimals be conditionally removed, if `number > 0`.

Tried with format function, and `map_dbl`. It shows error. Aim is to remove .00 from 1.00, 10.00.

```
kk= c(0.001,0.01,1.00,10.00)

number <-function(number){
  if(number>0){
    result <- format(number,nsmall = 0)
  return(result)
  }

}

map_dbl(kk,number)
```

> Actual : Error: Can't coerce element 1 from a character to a double

expected : 0.001,0.01,1,10

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55398598/5403217 this could be helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want a character vector as the output:

```
sapply(c(0.001, 0.01, 1, 10), 
    function(x) ifelse(x<1, x, round(x,0)))
[1] "0.001" "0.01"  "1"     "10"
```

To use a character vector to label an axis in a ggplot:

```
library(ggplot2)

axisLabels <- function(x) ifelse(x<1, x, as.character(round(x, 0)))

df <- data.frame(group=letters[1:5],
                 value=c(.023, .0473, 1.2, 1.5, 1.9))

ggplot(df, aes(x=group, y=value)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity") +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 2, .1),
                       labels=sapply(seq(0,2,.1), axisLabels))
```

[image]

Comment: I want as numeric vector to apply as sequence in ggplot.

Comment: Are you doing mathematical operations with this varying-precision numeric vector, or just labeling parts of the graph?

Comment: I don't think what you're asking for is possible.

Comment: just axis ticks labeling part only but i am trying with full automation,  no manual labeling. so this character may not be useful to define seq in ggplot.  want to display 10 instead of 10.00.    0.01 as is.

Comment: See updated answer for ggplot example. I don't see it as "manual" labeling, since it's a pure function that converts any numeric object to a properly formatted character based on the rule you defined. You could use this in any graph you've already made.